# DataFilter vs PushedFilter in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

What is the difference b/w DataFilter vs PushedFilter?

When partition filter is not used, I expect the filters to go to PushedFilter if predicate pushdown happened. Which is happening as expected. I also found `DataFilter` in the phycial plan.

I want to know what are `DataFilter` in the query? How it is different from PushedFilter?

[image: Spark Physical Plan]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is DataFilter in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75302326/what-is-datafilter-in-pyspark)

Answer (score -1):

As opposed to reading a file into memory and then applying the filter(s) - which is a waste of CPU cycles and bandwidth, the data can be filtered as the files are read from the bare metal. That is what DataFilter is.

Comment: "filtered as the files are read from the bare metal" thats happens when we have data partitioned right ? In that case both `DataFilter` and `PushedFilter` will be empty and we will have `PartitionFilter`.