# What is DataFilter in pyspark?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am seeing something called as `DataFilter` in my query execution plan:

```
FileScan parquet [product_id#12,price#14] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(product_id#12)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[gs://monsoon-credittech.appspot.com/spark_datasets/products_parquet_dtc], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(product_id)], ReadSchema: struct<product_id:int,price:int>
```

There is a

- PartitionFilters: []
- PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(product_id)]
- DataFilters: [isnotnull(product_id#12)]

I understand `PartitionFilter` and `PushedFilter`. But, what is the `DataFilter` that is showing up here? There is an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70457488/datafilter-vs-pushedfilter-in-spark). However, the definition of `DataFilter` given there is exactly what I think `PushedFilter` is (Also, that answer has 1 downvote). So, Is my understanding of `PushedFilter` wrong? If not, then, what is `DataFilter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This explanation is for Spark's latest version at the time of this post (3.3.1).

`PushedFilters` are kind of a subset of `DataFilters`, you can see this in [`DataSourceScanExec.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fbbcf9434ac070dd4ced4fb9efe32899c6db12a9/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/DataSourceScanExec.scala#L373-L382). They are the `DataFilters` whose predicates we can push down to filter on the metadata of the file you're trying to read in instead of against the data itself. Filtering against the metadata is of course way quicker then filtering against the data itself, because you might be able to skip reading large chunks of data when doing that.

So to structure everything, we have:

- **PartitionFilters**: Filters on partition columns. Enable you to disregard directories within your parquet file.
- **DataFilters**: Filters on non-partition columns.

  - **PushedFilters**: those `DataFilters` whose predicates we can push down
  - So when a filter is a `DataFilter` but not a `PushedFilter`, it means that we can't push down the predicate to filter on the underlying file's metadata.

##### Example

Let's take this example of parquet files (not all file formats support predicate pushdown, but parquet files do):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val df = Seq(
  (1,2,3),
  (2,2,3),
  (3,20,300),
  (1,24,299),
).toDF("colA", "colB", "colC")

df.write.partitionBy("colA").mode("overwrite").parquet("datafilter.parquet")
```

So we're simply writing a parquet file that is partitioned by the `colA` column. The file structure looks like this:

```
datafilter.parquet/
├── colA=1
│   ├── part-00000-55cb3320-f145-4d64-8cba-55a72111c0c8.c000.snappy.parquet
│   └── part-00003-55cb3320-f145-4d64-8cba-55a72111c0c8.c000.snappy.parquet
├── colA=2
│   └── part-00001-55cb3320-f145-4d64-8cba-55a72111c0c8.c000.snappy.parquet
├── colA=3
│   └── part-00002-55cb3320-f145-4d64-8cba-55a72111c0c8.c000.snappy.parquet
└── _SUCCESS
```

Let's have a look at the 3 filter types:

##### PartitionFilter

```
spark.read.parquet("./datafilter.parquet").filter(col("colA") < 10).explain

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) ColumnarToRow
+- FileScan parquet [colB#165,colC#166,colA#167] Batched: true, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:somePath/spark-tests/datafilter.parquet], PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(colA#167), (colA#167 < 10)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<colB:int,colC:int>
```

Here you see that our filter is a `PartitionFilter`, since our data has been partitioned by `colA` we can easily filter on the directories.

##### PushedFilter

```
spark.read.parquet("./datafilter.parquet").filter(col("colB") < 10).explain

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter (isnotnull(colB#172) AND (colB#172 < 10))
+- *(1) ColumnarToRow
   +- FileScan parquet [colB#172,colC#173,colA#174] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(colB#172), (colB#172 < 10)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:somePath/spark-tests/datafilter.parquet], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(colB), LessThan(colB,10)], ReadSchema: struct<colB:int,colC:int>
```

Here you see our filter (`colB < 10`) makes part of the `DataFilters`. This is because `colB` is not a partition column.

It also is part of the `PushedFilters`, because this is a predicate we can push down. Parquet files store minimum and maximum values of chunks as metadata. So if the minimum value of a chunk is larger than 10, we know we can skip reading this chunk.

##### Non PushedFilters

```
spark.read.parquet("./datafilter.parquet").filter(col("colB") < col("colC")).explain

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter ((isnotnull(colB#179) AND isnotnull(colC#180)) AND (colB#179 < colC#180))
+- *(1) ColumnarToRow
   +- FileScan parquet [colB#179,colC#180,colA#181] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(colB#179), isnotnull(colC#180), (colB#179 < colC#180)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:somePath/spark-tests/datafilter.parquet], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(colB), IsNotNull(colC)], ReadSchema: struct<colB:int,colC:int>
```

This filter is more complicated. `colB < colC` is not a filter that we can push down to filter onto the metadata of the parquet file. That means that we need to read the full data and filter afterwards in memory.

Comment: to the rescue again!! It makes perfect sense now. Thank you. However, I gotta ask - If you look at the output of your explain commands, both the DataFilters (Pushed and Non Pushed) are showing up as separate filter lines after the FileScan line as well. Are the pushed filters computed again? How to read this explain output? This might be outside of the scope of this question hence, I have asked a separate question on this as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75301799/pyspark-same-filter-as-the-predicate-applied-after-scan-even-after-the-predica

Comment: Ahhhh that's a great question, I've answered it on your other post! :)